# android question

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am trying to run Apidemos sample on my PC.
for that fst i hav launched AVD nd then run tht Apidemos app..
but it is giving me following errors...

```
[2010-10-16 10:33:43 - ApiDemos] Performing com.example.android.apis.ApiDemos activity launch
[2010-10-16 10:33:44 - ApiDemos] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'apidemoavd'
[2010-10-16 10:33:44 - ApiDemos] **WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!**
[2010-10-16 10:33:44 - ApiDemos] **Device API version is 7 (Android 2.1-update1)**
[2010-10-16 10:33:44 - ApiDemos] Uploading ApiDemos.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-10-16 10:33:52 - ApiDemos] **Failed to upload ApiDemos.apk on device 'emulator-5554'**
[2010-10-16 10:33:52 - ApiDemos] **java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!
[2010-10-16 10:33:52 - ApiDemos] Launch canceled!**
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the API level warning, check [uses-sdk element](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html#minsdkversion).

The failure seems to be caused by a disconnected device. Remember that you should [allow USB debugging](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Comment: Maybe the easier way would be to first check that adb is working through the command line (with 'adb devices' for example)

Comment: According to his console log, he's using an emulator. So 'Allow USB debugging' is either checked by default or does not need to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps recommended in the documentation: [Eclipse isn't talking to the emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/troubleshooting.html#eclipse)

Let us know if that works. There are several more things that can be done if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please:

1. Open the SDK manager
2. Then download the latest APIs and API Tools from here
3. Then you need to start new AVD using one of the downloaded APIs